# Convert All Session Values into String

Tags: php, session

hi i have many session values in my project and i use the syntext for session is

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $somevalue;
```

this things is implemented in may pages around 2000 pages. now i want to replace this thing to

```
$_SESSION['username'] = (string)$somevalue
```

in all the pages simultaneously. how can i do this in dreamwaver. please help me. there are many different session values used in my pages.

Is there any way to convert all session values into string simultaneosly. 
i mean any regex method like $_SESSION[*.*] = (string) like this. or any other method. please tell me .

Thanks.

Comment: you want it from Dreamweaver or PHP...?

Comment: Find/Replace function can't help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends of what version of PHP you have. For >=5.3, use Peter's version, for <5.3, use

```
function stringify($item)
{
    return (string)$item;
}

$_SESSION = array_map('stringify', $_SESSION);
```

Comment: And if it is 5.3 ? where's the = ?

Answer (score 1):

`array_map` function is probably what you are looking for:

```
$_SESSION = array_map(function($item) { return (string)$item; }, $_SESSION);
```

PHP 5.3 is required for anonymous function, in earlier versions you have to pass function name as first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want it *in your 2000 code files* instead of converting the values at runtime in your script: Don't know if Dreamweaver supports regex search and replace and what the backreference chars are. But try replacing this

```
\$_SESSION\['[^']+'\]\s*=\s*
```

with this:

```
$0(string)
```

The `$0` is the backreference to the matched pattern. If that doesn't work, try `\0` or `\\0` instead.

Answer (score -1):

You could use: **session_encode()**

"session_encode — Encodes the current session data as a session encoded string"
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-encode.php

***(*Must call session_start() before using session_encode().)***

```
session_start();
    
    $_SESSION['login_ok'] = true;
    $_SESSION['nome'] = 'sica';
    $_SESSION['inteiro'] = 34;
    
    echo session_encode();
    
    this code will print
    
    login_ok|b:1;nome|s:4:"sica";inteiro|i:34;
```

Answer (score -1):

**json_encode** Works for basic needs:

```
My_Session_As_String = json_encode($_SESSION);
```